# Convert Strings into data.frame using R

Tags: r

I have 1000+ rows of string which I extracted from a column of an Excel worksheet. Here's how the data looks like (3 rows):

Chicken(31%);Duck(16%);Wild duck(14%);Turkey(10%);Pigeon(4%);Goose(4%);Wild bird(4%);Tree sparrow(2%)

Tree sparrow(2%)

Chicken(1%)

I need to put the data into a table (for this example: 8 columns x 3 rows). Can anyone help?

```
x <- c("Chicken(31%);Duck(16%);Wild duck(14%);Turkey(10%);Pigeon(4%);Goose(4%);Wild bird(4%);Tree sparrow(2%)", 
"Tree sparrow(2%)", "Chicken(1%)")
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is the semicolon the separator for columns? What values do you want to fill with if a row has less than 8 entries?

Answer (score 2):

There is most likely more concise way but you can try something like this:

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)

# Drop empty lines if any
txt <- Filter(function(x) !stri_isempty(stri_trim(x)),  x)
# Extract matches
matches <- stri_match_all_regex(txt, "([\\w\\s]+)\\(([1-9]+)%\\);?")

matches[[1]]

##      [,1]               [,2]           [,3]
## [1,] "Chicken(31%);"    "Chicken"      "31"
## [2,] "Duck(16%);"       "Duck"         "16"
## [3,] "Wild duck(14%);"  "Wild duck"    "14"
## [4,] "Pigeon(4%);"      "Pigeon"       "4" 
## [5,] "Goose(4%);"       "Goose"        "4" 
## [6,] "Wild bird(4%);"   "Wild bird"    "4" 
## [7,] "Tree sparrow(2%)" "Tree sparrow" "2" 

# Rearrange
rows <- lapply(
   matches,
   function(x) setNames(as.list(as.numeric(x[, 3])), x[, 2]))

rbindlist(rows, fill=TRUE)

##    Chicken Duck Wild duck Pigeon Goose Wild bird Tree sparrow
## 1:      31   16        14      4     4         4            2
## 2:      NA   NA        NA     NA    NA        NA            2
## 3:       1   NA        NA     NA    NA        NA           NA
```

Regex explanation

```
([\\w\\s]+) #  At least one word character or whitespace *, 1st group
\\( # Left parenthesis
([1-9]+) # At least one digit. You can replace + with {1,2}, 2nd group
% # Percent sign
\\) # Right parenthesis
;? # Optional semicolon
```

* Could be `\\w[\\w\\s]+`

Comment: Thanks a lot Tyler Rinker and zero323 for your guidance. Zero323's code is exactly what I want to do. Thank you both!

Comment: Is it possible to explain the regex ([\\w\\s]+)\\(([1-9]+)%\\);? in details? I adapt your code but getting NA in all lists of my output. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The data is slightly different now (e.g. Chicken (15.25%); Duck (10,24%). There's a space in between the name and %, and% with 2 decimal point. I modified the regex to: ([\\w\\s]+)(\\s)\\(([1-9]+)%\\);? but still getting NA.

Comment: I modified the regex to "([\\w-\\w\\s]+) \\(([1-9]+\\.[0-9][0-9]?)%\\);?" and it works now. However, I lost the first word of the string. in this case "Chicken (15.25%)". Any idea :-(

Comment: Something like this: `"(\\w[\\w\\s]+)\\(([1-9]+\\.[0-9][0-9]?)%\\);?"`?

Comment: Yes, your correct worked! I came to a bumper again. Somehow, the regex doesn't recognize percentage with "10" like 10.24% or 10.35%. Others 15.25% .. are fine. Hmm... what's wrong? I've been stucked for the last few hours

Comment: Typo :) should be `[0-9]+` instead of `[1-9]+`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's on possible solution:

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(strsplit(gsub("\\(\\d+%\\)", "", x), ";"))



##   Chicken Duck Goose Pigeon Tree sparrow Turkey Wild bird Wild duck
## 1       1    1     1      1            1      1         1         1
## 2       0    0     0      0            1      0         0         0
## 3       1    0     0      0            0      0         0         0
```